# How to get response from div which is having link in another div

Tags: php, html, css

I am really tired for searching this can someone help me... help will be really appreciate.

My question is Suppose I have one div element eg.

```
<div name="div1" class="demo">
```

and I have some links in that div so my code will something like:

```
<div name="div1" class="demo"> 
 <ul>
    <li> <a>Example1</a></li>  
    <li> <a> Example2</a></li>  
</div>
```

and I have another div element which is

```
<div name="div2" class="demo2"> </div>
```

and I Now what i want, when i will click the link in first div eg. Example1.. I want the response of that link into div no 2 . IE on the another div which is

```
<div name="div2" class="demo2">
```

Comment: What do you mean with "response of that link"? Please put your code into a snippet

Comment: given how you have made your `<a>` tag you can't do this in PHP, you need to use javascript since you're not reloading or loading another page

Answer (score 0):

This is provided in html, for instance

```html
<div id="name"> 
<ul> 
  <li> <a href="yourpage.html#name2" > Example1 </a> </li>
  <li> <a> Example2 </a></li> 
</ul>
</div>
```

Then in your reference div ensure you have given it the referring id, for instance

```html
<div id="name2" class="demo2"> </div>
```

When you click on first link it should bring up the div with the id requested. Of course styling effects such as z-index can be added.

Comment: Thanks, I've made the relevant changes

Comment: I am totally new to this programming world... though i have learnt HTML CSS and PHP so how can i achieve this with this three techniques....

Comment: php is a server side language, which means that you can use it to generate the list, maybe pulling the list from the server, then use it to id the divs, but the basic html functionality above should work.

Comment: let me put my question again, I have two div elements side by side. First div is <div name=div1" class=demo1> <ul> <li> <a href=url.php> Example </a> </li> </ul> </div> and now what my question is when user will click on this above link i.e. Example, then the requested page should open in the second div... and other div is <div name=div2 class=demo2>  </div>.... how to do that ?? I only know html css and php... is it possible to achieve this with this three languages only ????

Comment: for That you need *_javascript_ to change the style from `display:none` to `display:inline` using a onclick, for instance `<a onclick="display()"` then define the display function in javascript. Its the easiest method to achieve what you want. Alternatively use jquery to view a whole page as shown in the answer by @Nandan

Answer (score 0):

To be frank, you question is not understandable, However I am relating "Response" to "HTML" and "Link" to "Element".

So, Onclick of demo the content of demo will be moved to demo2.

Use JQUERY,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


$(".demo").on("click", function(e){
    $(".demo2").html($(this).html());
});
```